# django-admin-tools does not see some apps in dashboard

Tags: django, django-admin-tools

On devserver all works fine, but in production there are not some apps in admin dashboard.

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'admin_tools',
    'admin_tools.theming',
    'admin_tools.menu',
    'admin_tools.dashboard',

    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',

    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'file_resubmit',
    'django_pencil',

    'blog',
    'core',
    'gallery',
    'nav',
    'options',
    'pages',
    'themes',

    'django_cleanup',
)
```

Here is code of CustomIndexDashboard.

```
class CustomIndexDashboard(Dashboard):
    """
    Custom index dashboard for coffee.
    """
    def init_with_context(self, context):
        site_name = get_admin_site_name(context)
        # append a link list module for "quick links"
        self.children.append(modules.LinkList(
            _('Quick links'),
            layout='inline',
            draggable=False,
            deletable=False,
            collapsible=False,
            children=[
                [_('Return to site'), '/'],
                [_('Change password'),
                 reverse('%s:password_change' % site_name)],
                [_('Log out'), reverse('%s:logout' % site_name)],
            ]
        ))

        self.children.append(
            modules.ModelList(u'Navigation', [
                'nav.*',
            ])
        )
        self.children.append(
            modules.ModelList(u'Content', [
                'pages.*',
                'django_pencil.*',
            ])
        )

        self.children.append(
            modules.ModelList(u'Gallery', [
                'gallery.*',
            ])
        )
        self.children.append(
            modules.ModelList(u'Blog', [
                'blog.*',
            ])
        )

        self.children.append(
            modules.ModelList(u'Options', [
                'options.*',
            ])
        )
```

In dashboard there are not 'pages' and 'gallery' apps.
If I turn off django-admin-tools, then those apps appears.

Answer (score 1):

Verify if DashboardPreferences on your production site has old configuration. Create a view just to reset current configuration to make sure Preferences are clean.

```
def reset_dashboard(request):
    prefs = DashboardPreferences.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    prefs.delete()
    prefs = DashboardPreferences(user=request.user)
    prefs.data = '{}'
    prefs.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:index'))
```